# Clock Widget on tapping does not open

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, app-widgets, clock

I currently switched to Samsung Galaxy s3! The first two days I would tap on the digital clock widget on the home screen to access the alarm. However, yesterday the software of the phone updated by itself. And after the update, when i tap on the  digital clock widget on the home screen, nothing happens. I cant access the alarm clock by tapping the clock widget anymore. please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

On my S3, the clock widget no longer launches the clock app or alarm. There is, however, a designated alarm app that may be used. That, or you can use a clock widget from the Play Store, there are quite a number that offer a similar experience to Samsung's default Clock app, that allow you to launch a shortcut when tapped on.